How to unzip a zip from macOS on Windows and is the “__MACOSX” folder in a Mac-made Zip the right place to look for the Zip contents?
Somebody sent me a bunch  of PDF files as a Zip from their Mac laptop. Now I am trying to extract the PDF files.
I am on Windows 10 I can extract a folder __MACOSX and inside it, a folder  containing a number of PDF files, but when I see the files in binary, they are not actually in the correct PDF format.
Near the start of the file I see  some plain-text insertions, such as ATTR or com.dropbox.attrs  and apparently  some binary insertions, probably the values of those attributes.
Is this a quirk of Zip? Or were those files originally corrupted, such as when the sender  downloaded them from dropbox?  Or am I looking in a wrong place?
Isn't the folder __MACOSX where I should look for my files?

NOTE: My question is not  heoretic, like what __MACOSX was intended for and why Apple does not use standard file formats.
My question is purely practical: I urgently need the PDF files they sent to me, so how can I extract them  in a usable form (not corrupted with those useless "attribute" insertions) (or how can I remove those insertions to repair the PDF files?)
I can imagine that a part of the solution will be to borrow a Mac laptop from somebody  and open the Zip there, but I have no idea of how to open it on a Mac. Or, how to transfer them back -- maybe with a USB stick?
Please help with fool-proof step-by-step instructions. If I knew what to do, I would not ask.

Does this answer your question? What is “__MACOSX” folder I keep seeing in Zip files made by people on OS X?

These metadata attributes seem to be added by Dropbox. These metadata files may either be ignored, or perhaps the original files should be correctly downloaded from Dropbox.

I've seen those macosx folders in compressed folder for years, and I cannot recall a single time this is folder has contained the data I needed. The files I wanted were always outside that folder and were fully functional. Inside that folder were some sort of metadata that usually has the same file names as the data I wanted, but, again, were NOT the files themselves. I think what you're seeing is an incorrect/badly formatted compressed archive, and the contents of the macosx folder is just confusing things. Have the sender create and send you another copy.

As above. The same for desktop Linux.

You may wish to strip the zip down to just the Windows content as that __MACOSX fork is not needed on Windows.
Beware this cmd script does not do extensive checking but is a template for your own enhancements. You should have a work "copy" of the MAC files in a working folder to avoid problems the adjust the results as you wish.
Here is used with a drag and drop example. The script is in one folder and the VBExample.zip is in its own folder. We can see its subfolders but they are NOT yet unpacked.

Before:

After where the zip is backed up and reduced in size without the fork and as a bonus the unpacked contents are there (can be deleted if you wish):

This script comes with "Zero Guarantee" of working with all Mac zips. It works with the more common variants. Always use on a copy of the one you got. Then delete working copies as desired.
if not exist "%~dpn1.zip" goto EOF
pushd "%~dp1"

copy "%~dpn1.zip" "%~dpn1-backup.zip"
tar -xf "%~dpn1.zip"
rd /s /q __MACOSX
tar -a -cf "%~dpn1.zip" "%~n1\*.*"

if not exist "%~dpn1.zip" echo FAILED & pause
REM [optionally remove the unpacked folder] RD /S /Q "%~n1"

:exit
popd

Reasons for failure may include when a filename does not match the foldername, see the new zip is too small as 1 KB.

We can easily rebuild in such case using send to correctly named zip folder.


Or ensure the outer zip name reflects the inner folder name.

